How to play a song with default player without leaving app
My app has a path to a song it wants to play.  Is there anyway to play the song in the default music player in the background without leaving my app?   My minSDK = 26.  I want to interact with the default music player that is already launched in memory and, presumably, is running as a foreground service.
I followed this guide, and then..
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(path));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);

This plays the song but it opens some mini player in the foreground.  I want it to simply open the song in the main default music player that is already running as a foreground service.

This question is similar to: Starting an Intent to Launch an app to Background in Android. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note that launching a different app (music player) should have some explicit user feedback to prevent malware/bad actors. User is free to background the music player explicitly after seeing which app is playing music/content.

Ok, I made it more clear.

Even if the music app is currently playing, the music app service will need to be written to handle third-party intents but that is not advised, see answers/links in: What is the use of intent-filter in the manifest for a service?

When I say "Hey Google, play next song" it will interact with the default music player and play the next song.  That is essentially what I want to do.  How come Google can do it?

Based on the Google Assistant docs, they accomplish this using the media session APIs, if the music player supports URI-based actions (ACTION_PLAY_FROM_URI). I forgot that the media session API supported playing from URIs; I am used to them for working with existing playlists (e.g., play/pause, forward, reverse). You'll have to poke around to see if there is a way to determine if the current media session (assuming there is one) supports those actions, as those are not required.

Thanks for clue.  I'll investigate it further.

You can use the MediaPlayer API provided by Google to play your music. You can refer to it here. This way, you will not need to leave the app.
https://developer.android.com/media/platform/mediaplayer

This is interesting thank you.  I got it working.  Curiously it will play more than one song at the same time unless you explicitly stop the first song.  I'm going to continue to look for a solution for the Samsung Music player because that is stock in most phones I believe and has a UI the user can go to should they want.

@slowcoder Samsung music player is NOT stock in most phones.  It's not available at all for any phones that aren't Samsung.  Only 20% of phones worldwide are Samsung, but 75% are android, so about 25-30% of android phones are Samsung.  And then, not all Samsung phone have the same software and may not have that player.

Thanks for the info.  What I'm going to do is change my target audience to users of Samsung phones lol.
